# How to get bounding-box (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) for an given point (lat, long) and distance in km in python?

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude, geopandas

How to get bounding-box (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) tuple for an given point (lat, long) and given distance in kilometers (int or float) with python ?

The given distance is the half of the diagonal of the bounding-box I am looking for.

```py
paris_point = (48.8588548, 2.347035)
distance_km = 20

#Get bounding_box
def get_bounding_box(point, distance):
    ???
    return (minx, miny, maxx, maxy)

result = get_bounding_box(paris_point, distance_km)
```

minx is the longitude of the southwestern corner

miny is the latitude of the southwestern corner

maxx is the longitude of the northeastern corner

maxy is the latitude of the northeastern corner

I try with geopandas but I don't find anything...
Is there a lib that can do this?

Can you help me please ?
Thanks

Comment: Bounding box is usually a `(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)` tuple. For a single point its coordinates are the same as for the point itself and that distance would be 0. Are there multiple points? For an useful answer please consider rephrasing your question, include your current code and some sample data and perhaps a drawing to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Yes, you're right, i reformule.

Answer (score 0):

Bounding box in this context can be bit confusing as there's only a single point object. Lets just call it a square buffer.
While [Geopanadas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide.html) is kind of overkill here, it conveniently wraps & provides all the functions you'd need. But for less dependencies you could use it's underlying libraries - [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) & [pyproj](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/) - directly as well.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import pyproj
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import transform
from math import sqrt

# with GeoPandas
def get_buffer_box_geopandas(point_lat_long, distance_km):
    # distance is d/2 of the square buffer around the point,
    # from center to corner;
    # find buffer width in meters
    buffer_width_m = (distance_km * 1000) / sqrt(2)
    (p_lat, p_long) = point_lat_long

    # Geopandas Geodataframe with a single point
    # EPSG:4326 sets Coordinate Reference System to WGS84 to match input
    wgs84_pt_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry = gpd.points_from_xy([p_long],[p_lat], crs='EPSG:4326'))
    
    # find suitable projected coordinate system for distance
    utm_crs = wgs84_pt_gdf.estimate_utm_crs()
    # reproject to UTM -> create square buffer (cap_style = 3) around point -> reproject back to WGS84
    wgs84_buffer = wgs84_pt_gdf.to_crs(utm_crs).buffer(buffer_width_m, cap_style=3).to_crs('EPSG:4326')
    # wgs84_buffer.bounds returns bounding box as pandas dataframe, 
    # .values[0] will extract first row as an array
    return wgs84_buffer.bounds.values[0]

# with Shapely & pyproj
def get_buffer_box_shapely(point_lat_long, distance_km):
    buffer_width_m = (distance_km * 1000) / sqrt(2)
    (p_lat, p_long) = point_lat_long

    # create Shapely Point object, coodrinates as x,y
    wgs84_pt = Point(p_long, p_lat)
    # set up projections WGS84 (lat/long coordinates) for input and 
    # UTM to measure distance
    # https://epsg.io/4326
    wgs84 = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:4326')
    # sample point in France - UTM zone 31N 
    # Between 0°E and 6°E, northern hemisphere between equator and 84°N
    # https://epsg.io/32631
    utm = pyproj.CRS('EPSG:32631')
    
    # transformers:
    project_wgs84_to_utm = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(wgs84, utm, always_xy=True).transform
    project_utm_to_wgs84 = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(utm, wgs84, always_xy=True).transform

    # tranform Point to UTM
    utm_pt = transform(project_wgs84_to_utm, wgs84_pt)
    # create square buffer (cap_style = 3) around the Point
    utm_buffer = utm_pt.buffer(buffer_width_m, cap_style=3)
    # tranform buffer back to WGS84 and get bounds in lat / long 
    wgs84_bounds = transform(project_utm_to_wgs84, utm_buffer).bounds
    return wgs84_bounds

paris_point = (48.8588548, 2.347035)
distance_km = 20

get_buffer_box_geopandas(paris_point, distance_km)
# array([ 2.15209704, 48.73039383,  2.54099598, 48.98700028])

get_buffer_box_shapely(paris_point, distance_km)
# (2.152097043192064, 48.73039383319076, 2.540995981145973, 48.98700027642409)
```

For most use cases it's probably more practical to use a round buffer and radius instead of square buffer and distance from center to the corner.